# how to make wrapper works on mac os x

Tags: java, macos, maven, wrapper

I have a big projects working on a **linux server**, I downloaded the jars to my mac os x 10.10.1 machine.

I changed the pom.xml to this:

```
<generatorConfigurations>
    <generatorConfiguration>
        <generator>jsw</generator>
    <includes>
        <include>macosx-universal-64</include>
        <include>macosx-universal-32</include>
    </includes>
</generatorConfiguration>
```

When I run: two new files have been generated, which are:

```
wrapper-macosx-universal-32
wrapper-macosx-universal-64
```

However, I am getting these errors:
Unable to locate any of the following operational binaries:

```
  /bla bla /bin/./wrapper-macosx-universal-64 (Found but not executable.)
  /bla bla /bin/./wrapper-macosx-universal-32 (Found but not executable.)
  /bla bla /bin/./wrapper
```

I have no idea how to fix that.

I found a jar called wrapper.jar, should I replace it with a jar for mac? if yes which one should I get from these http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp

I am able to provide u with whatever information you need.

Comment: You have to buy a license from Tanuki, cause the 64 bit is not in the community edition.

Comment: @khmarbaise could you support with a proof please? (just to show my manager) plus can't i use the 32 in this case?

Comment: @khmarbaise i can see a community version on the link i provided, for mac universal. isn't that correct?